# I am trying to implement a Chronometer with OnChronometerTickListener

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I basically want a stopwatch activity in my app that will vibrate the device after 30 seconds have elapsed and sound a notification alert at 60 seconds. I am new to app development so please don't hound me for missing an obvious answer.

I know I need `Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener` - but not sure how to implement?

```
public void shotClockStart(View v) {

        Chronometer shotclock = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono1);
        shotclock.start();
        long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - shotclock.getBase();
        if (timeElapsed >= 30000) {
            //  HERE I WANT A VIBRATION ON THE DEVICE.
        }else if(timeElapsed>=60000){
            //HERE I WANT A NOTIFICATION ALERT 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `shotclock.setOnChronometerTickListener()`

Comment: could you elaborate please?

Comment: Besides you need to put handling code into tick event handler function, your condition is wrong, you will always get into first one after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the listener on the `Chronometer`

```
public void shotClockStart(View v) {
    Chronometer shotclock = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono1);
    shotclock.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            if (timeElapsed >= 30000) {
                //  HERE I WANT A VIBRATION ON THE DEVICE.
            }else if(timeElapsed>=60000){
                //HERE I WANT A NOTIFICATION ALERT
            }
        }
    });
    shotclock.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    shotclock.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. I can see what i missed now. I have upvoted but doesnt show because of my rep